# Find column names when row element meets a criteria Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

This is a basic question. I've got a square array with the rows and columns summed up. Eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0]], index = ["a","b","c","d"], columns = ["a","b","c","d"])
df["sumRows"] = df.sum(axis = 1)
df.loc["sumCols"] = df.sum()
```

This returns:

```
In [100]: df
Out[100]: 
         a  b  c  d  sumRows
a        0  0  1  0        1
b        0  0  1  0        1
c        1  0  0  0        1
d        0  1  0  0        1
sumCols  1  1  2  0        4
```

I need to find the column labels for the sumCols rows which matches 0. At the moment I am doing this:

```
[df.loc["sumCols"] == 0].index
```

But this return a strange index type object. All I want is a list of values that match this criteria i.e: ['d'] in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` expression to filter series and if you want a list instead of index as result, you can call `.tolist()` on the index object:

```
(df.loc['sumCols'] == 0)[lambda x: x].index.tolist()
# ['d']
```

Or:

```
df.loc['sumCols'][lambda x: x == 0].index.tolist()
# ['d']
```

---

Without explicitly creating the `sumCols` and if you want to check which column has sum of zero, you can do:

```
df.sum()[lambda x: x == 0].index.tolist()
# ['d']
```

Check rows:

```
df.sum(axis = 1)[lambda x: x == 0].index.tolist()
# []
```

Note: The `lambda` expression approach is as fast as the vectorized method for subsetting, functional style and can be written easily in a one-liner if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

There is two ways (the index object can be converted to an interable like a list).

Do that with the columns:

```
columns = df.columns[df.sum()==0]
columns = list(columns)
```

Or you can rotate the Dataframe and treat columns as rows:

```
list(df.T[df.T.sumCols == 0].index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres a simple method using query after transposing

```
df.T.query('sumCols == 0').index.tolist()
```